# Palindrome checker using user input and while loop in bash

Tags: linux, bash, loops, while-loop, palindrome

I'm trying to make a bash script that checks if a word is a palindrome for my homework assignment, but I can't get my while loop to work properly. The script should keep running and asking for a palindrome, until the user gives a palindrome. Can someone more experienced help me out with this and maybe explain what I did wrong.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -le 2 ]           
then 
    echo "Enter the word"
    read input                  
fi 
echo $input > temp         
reverse=`rev temp`     
echo $reverse              


while [ ! $input==$reverse ]
do  echo "Not a palindrome"
    read input 

done
echo "it is a palindrome"    
rm temp
```

Comment: You are missing spaces around `==`, and you better quote the arguments, in case someone enters a word which contains spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail;

while true; do
    echo -n "Enter the word: ";
    IFS=$'\n\t ' read -d$'\n' -r inputword restofsentence;
    if [[ -n "${inputword}" && -z "${restofsentence}" ]] ; then
        reverse="$( rev <( echo "${inputword}" ) )";
        if [[ "${reverse}" == "${inputword}" ]] ; then
            echo "it is a palindrome";
            exit 0;
        else
            echo "Not a palindrome";
            echo "";
            echo "";
        fi;
    fi;
done;
```

I'm not sure what function the `$#` (number of cli arguments) served, in your example, as you weren't using the cli arguments; so i've left that part out.

---

As for what it all does:

```
set -euo pipefail;
```

Effectively enables "strict mode". Making BASH less of a shitty scripting language. It doesn't really have much of an effect in this script, but it's good practice to always have that in every script by default.

```
while true; do
```

Start a loop and keep repeating it forever.

```
echo -n "Enter the word: ";
```

The `-n` inhibits the usual newline at the end of the sentence.

```
IFS=$'\n\t '
```

Explicitly sets the Internal Field Separator. This means bash's interpretation of what a word is, is the input "broken apart" on newlines (`\n`), tab characters (`\t`) and spaces (' '); generally this is the default value, but its always good practise to manually set `IFS` either on a per-script basis, or for every `read`-like command.

```
read -d$'\n' -r inputword restofsentence;
```

Reads user input up to delimiter newline (`-d$'\n'`), meaning the enter key. Don't allow backslash-escapes `-r` to be used for things like multi-line input. The inputline is split into words based on the earlier `IFS`; after which the first word goes into `inputword`, and potential 2nd/3rd/...-words go into `restofsentence`.

```
if [[ -n "${inputword}" && -z "${restofsentence}" ]] ; then
```

We expect `inputword` to have a value (non-empty) and we expect `restofsentence` to be empty. If that is not the case, we simply let the `while`-loop repeat and ask for input again. This way we never deal with empty input (because `inputword` would be empty) nor with multi-word input (because `restofsentence` wouldn't be empty).

```
reverse="$( rev <( echo "${inputword}" ) )";
```

We echo the `inputword` into a virtual file, and pass that to the `rev` program, which `echo`s the reverse value. We store that in variable `reverse`.

The fact that we aren't using a real file (which is stored on the filesystem, instead of only in memory), saves us from having to clean that up later.

```
if [[ "${reverse}" == "${inputword}" ]] ; then
```

We compare if the `inputword` and `reverse` are identical, if they are then we're dealing with a palindrome.

```
exit 0;
```

Once we've had a successful palindrome, we quit (exitcode `0` indicates there was no error).

---

The program (specifically the `while`-loop) keeps repeating forever until a successful palindrome is found.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
#!/bin/bash

while :; do
    read -p "Enter a word: "

    if [[ ${REPLY} == "$(rev <(printf %s "${REPLY}"))" ]]; then
        echo "It is a palindrome."
        break
    fi

    echo "Not a palindrome."
done
```

Alternatively it can be done simpler like this but this isn't right since theoretically "It is a palindrome." will be still sent even if the loop breaking is not caused by correct input but other errors.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -p "Enter a word: "; [[ ${REPLY} != "$(rev <(printf %s "${REPLY}"))" ]]; do
    echo "Not a palindrome."
done

echo "It is a palindrome"
```

By the way it uses [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html).

One can create a function that reverses strings instead and that should be trivial but it's optional scope.

Answer (score 0):

First get it working.
You want to check for one argument. When the argument is given, assign it to input. Quote `$input` avoiding problems witch special characters and spaces. Add spaces around `==` to make it compare and calculate reverse again in the loop. I also used `$(rev temp)` what works better than backtics.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
    echo "Enter the word"
    read input
else
  input="$1"
fi
echo "$input" > temp
reverse=$(rev temp)
echo "$reverse"

while [ ! "$input" == "$reverse" ]
do
  echo "Not a palindrome"
  read input
  echo "$input" > temp
  reverse=$(rev temp)
done
echo "it is a palindrome"
rm temp
```

You can avoid a tmp file like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
    echo "Enter the word"
    read input
else
  input="$1"
fi
while [ ! "$input" == "$(rev <<< "${input}")" ]
do
  echo "Not a palindrome"
  read input
done
echo "it is a palindrome"
```